# How to groupBy the array of object and concat into single array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to group the array of objects based on the key and concat all the grouped objects into a single array. GroupBy based on the id

example,

**payload**

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'c'
  }
]
```

**expected response**

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'a'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'b'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'c'
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'b'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'c'
    }
  ]
]
```

All the matched elements are in the same array and all the arrays should be in a single array.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result using [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) easily

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "b",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "c",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "c",
  },
];

const map = new Map();
arr.forEach((o) => !map.has(o.id) ? map.set(o.id, [o]) : map.get(o.id).push(o));

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**2)** You can also achieve the result using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "b",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "c",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "c",
  },
];

const result = [...arr.reduce((map, curr) => {
  !map.has(curr.id) ? map.set(curr.id, [curr]) : map.get(curr.id).push(curr);
  return map;
}, new Map()).values()];
console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output full height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a object with ids array by using [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method, and get the object values by [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var s = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'c'
  }
];

//go through the input array and create a object with id's, group the values to gather
var ids = s.reduce((a, c) => {

  //check object has the `id` property, if not create a property and assign empty array
  if (!a[c.id])
    a[c.id] = [];

  //push the value into desidred object property
  a[c.id].push(c)

  //return the accumulator
  return a;

}, {});

//get the grouped array as values
var outPut = Object.values(ids);
console.log(outPut);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.redue` will help

```js
const input = [
  { id: 1, name: 'a' },
  { id: 1, name: 'b' },
  { id: 1, name: 'c' },
  { id: 2, name: 'b' },
  { id: 2, name: 'c' }
];
const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find(item => item.find(x => x.id === curr.id));
  node ? node.push(curr) : acc.push([curr]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `ids` using `Set` so you have a unique set of them,
then loop over those `ids` and filter the original array based on it.

```js
let objects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'a'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'c'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'b'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'c'
  }
]

let ids = [...new Set(objects.map(i => i.id))]
let result = ids.map(id => objects.filter(n =>  id === n.id))

console.log(result)
```